# Bold specific word within Redux Form's Form Field input

Tags: label, redux-form, react-redux-form

I have a `FormField` from `ReduxForm` that I want to make bold for its label. But I don't want to bold the entire label. Just a specific word within it. I know you can do this with a normal `label for` by placing a span with a class in vanilla html, but how do I do this with Redux Form?

Answer (score 1):

Just specify a `label` prop which accepts a string or a node:

```
export const renderField = ({ label, input, meta, ...props }) => (
  <div>
    <label>{ label }</label>
    <input { ...input } />
  </div>
);

// In your form
<Field component={renderField} label="Foo bar baz" />
<Field component={renderField} label={ <span>Foo <strong>bar</strong> baz</span> } />
```

Comment: doesn't ReduForm have to use FormField though?

Comment: Is `FormField` your custom component? Then yes, go ahead.